# How to override a gdb command in python, and then call the underlying gdb command after some argument processing (without making it recursive)

Tags: python, gdb

I have been reading lots of documentation and experimenting but unable to find an answer and hopefully someone can help me. I want to override the "break" gdb command in such a way, that the overriding function does some processing on the arguments and then issues the actual gdb "break" command (with the new arguments). I have also experimented with gdb hook command and right now the only solution that i can think of is to create a new gdb command which does the needful, but it would be great for my application if i could override the original gdb "break" command.

So, in short how do I make the following work (without it becoming recursive)?:

```
class BreakOverride (gdb.Command):
    "new break override."
    def __init__ (self):
        super (BreakOverride, self).__init__ ("break", gdb.COMMAND_BREAKPOINTS, gdb.COMPLETE_NONE, True)

    def invoke (self, arg, from_tty):
        #Do processing on the arg to create new_args and then call 
        #gdb.execute("break new_args");
        #without the above call becoming recursive back into this same function.

BreakOverride()
```

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this would be great, but I don't think there is currently any way to do it.  I believe there's a bug open about it.  And once I had a patch but I never went through the effort to submit it, sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I had hoped there might be a way. :)